# How to remove temporary layers so they don't show up in parameter lists

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox

ArcGis 10.2, arcpy. I have several tools in a Python toolbox that have a feature class parameter.  The parameter is defined as parameterType = “GPFeatureLayer”.   When running several tools in succession the list of choices for the parameter becomes cluttered with temporary layers created from previously run tools.   By temporary I mean layers created with arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management().  This list will sometimes include multiple occurrences of the same layer name.  I would like to remove all layers from wherever they are coming from so only those layers that are in the TOC show up as choices in the tool parameters.  I have tried arcpy.Delete_management() but that resulted in deleting the actual features the layer was generated from rather than the layer (OUCH!).   I have also tried emptying out the scratch GDB.  Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: What version is the toolbox that these tools are in? It seems not like it is not 10.x.

Comment: ArcGIS 10.2.1 Python 2.7

Comment: I am unaware of a GPFeatureClass.  Do you mean [GPFeatureLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Defining_parameter_data_types_in_a_Python_toolbox/001500000035000000/)?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the `in_memory` workspace?

Comment: Yes, the parameter type is **GPFeatureLayer.**  My mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. I did try clearing the in_memory workspace which did not have the desired effect.

Comment: Can you use the 'del' python keyword to delete the in moemory feature layer?

Answer (score 3):

After re-reading the documentation on Internal Layers http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/...0000000m000000, specifically:

> When you create a layer or table view using geoprocessing tools, the
>   new layer or table view is stored in an internal layer list, which is 
>   a different list from the ArcMap table of contents. This means that geoprocessing actually keeps two lists of layers and table views:
>
> - The list of layers in the ArcMap table of contents
> - The internal list of layers created by geoprocessing tools

I can see what I was doing wrong. I thought I was deleting the temporary layers by getting a list of layers for the data frame and deleting from that list:

```
def clearLayers():
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
    for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr) 
    del mxd
```

This was not clearing the internal layer list (layers created by other geoprocessing tools) that the python tools use in part to generate parameter lists. Having arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False had no effect on the internal layer list either (which it shouldn't).

To delete from the internal list I am using arcpy.Delete_management() on the temporary layer itself as in:

```
tempLyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer(features, layerName)

...do other stuff

arcpy.Delete_management(tempLyr, 'GPFeatureLayer')
```

Comment: 404 on your link for internal layers.  For 10.2: [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00210000000m000000)

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use the mapping module to [list layers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s30000002n000000) in the TOC?

Something like...

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(df)[0]
```

Then use this list to get names, data source, etc, and use it in a filter of your GPFeatureLayer parameter.

Comment: I am using the mapping module to delete the layers created by MakeFeatureLayer_management(), also setting arcpy.env.addOutputToMap = False so they are not in the TOC,but they still show up as parameters. I have not tried to filter the parameter list though.  I'll give that a shot